# LARAVEL Eloquent: link post to user then user to profile

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, table-relationships, laravel-5.6

I am aiming on retrieving the user image (from profile table column 'profile_img') and display on each post's footer.

I can retrieve the name of the author using `$post->author->name` and the profile picture using `$post->author->profile->profile_image` but it only works when i have a single record (post). when there is more than one record i get an error Trying to get property 'profile' of non-object (View: xampp/........../home.blade.php)

Can somebody show me where do i go wrong??

Models:

User

```
public function post() 
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post');  
}
public function profile()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Profile

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Post

```
public function author()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
}
```

controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class MainController extends Controller
{
  public function index() {
  $posts = Post::paginate(9);

return view('pages.home')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

home view

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
@foreach($posts as$posts)
<div>
  <div class="post-title"><h3>{{$post->title}}</h3></div>
  <div class="post-description">
    {!!mb_substr($post>body,10,rand(35,40)) !!} ....
  </div>
  <div class="featured-details">
    <div class="p-clearfix">
       <img class="authorimg"src="/storage/profile_images/{{ $post->author->profile->profile_image }}">
        <div class="author-title lite">{{ $post->author->name }}</div>
      <div class="lite thumbnail-date">{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
@endforeach

@else
  no post yet
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some issues in your home view. Try it again with this code and see.

**Home View**

```
@if(count($posts) > 0)
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div>
  <div class="post-title"><h3>{{$post->title}}</h3></div>
  <div class="post-description">
    {!!mb_substr($post>body,10,rand(35,40)) !!} ....
  </div>
  <div class="featured-details">
    <div class="p-clearfix">
       <img class="authorimg"src="/storage/profile_images/{{ $post->author->profile->profile_image }}">
        <div class="author-title lite">{{ $post->author->name }}</div>
      <div class="lite thumbnail-date">{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
@endforeach

@else
  no post yet
@endif
```

You can even go further and avoid the n+1 problem for authors by running your eloquent model query like this om your **controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class MainController extends Controller
{
  public function index() {
  $posts = Post::with("author")->paginate(9);

return view('pages.home')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Lamin Barrow for the reply, but still doesint work, if i return `$post->author` inside foreach loop only a single record is retrived

Comment: You have a `belongsTo` relationship between the `Post` and the `User` so the author will only return one user. If you want the inverse of it then you will get a `hasMany` post on the `User` model for `Post`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller index method try with :

```
public function index() {
  $posts = Post::with("author.profile")->paginate(9);

  return view('pages.home')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

And update post model relationship:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id'); // update to users table foreign key
}
```

Comment: Still the error Trying to get property 'profile' of non-object (View: xampp/........../home.blade.php) @Shipu